# Code lens not showing correct number of tests

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

In the VS 2013, I see number of unit tests for a method.

It works fine if I am calling the method directly from the TestMethod, but if I call sut from a helper/private method, the codelens does not seem to count that test.

I am using private method to pass different parameters to my test method and execute the test. I know I can use xls, csv or db to do that but I just want to do that in the code and make the test count.

Is there a way to make codelens count tests in this scenario?

MyClass.cs

```
    --1/1 passing ( this is fine)
    public bool MyMethbod (bool input)
    {

         return input
    }
```

MyClassTest.cs

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyMethod_ShuoldReturnTrue
{
   var returnValue = new MyClass().MyMethod(true);
   Assert.IsTrue(returnValue)
}
```

MyClass.cs

```
    --0/0 passing ( I am expecting codelens to show 1/1)
    public bool MyMethbod (bool input)
    {
         return input;
    }
```

MyClassTest.cs

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyMethod_ShuoldReturnTrue
{
    MyMethod_ShuoldReturnTrue_Refactored(true);
}

private void MyMethod_ShuoldReturnTrue_Refactored(bool someValue)
{
   var returnValue = new MyClass().MyMethod(someValue);
   Assert.AreEqual(returnValue, someValue);
}
```